# AngularJS Directives: Are we not supposed to use the suffix "start"?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is this a bug or is there documentation somewhere that says not to use the suffix "start" in the name of a directive?  Only the 'finish' directive works.

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
...
<body>
  <h2>Angular doesn't like the suffix 'start'</h2>
  <div this-is-the-start="abc"></div>
  <div this-is-the-finish="abc"></div>
</body>
...
</html>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('thisIsTheFinish', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: 'finish'
  }  
});

myApp.directive('thisIsTheStart', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
      template: 'start'
  }  
});
```

Code in action:
http://plnkr.co/edit/SrNncw?p=preview

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3589

Comment: Wow.  Basically, this is "ok" then.  Seems bogus.  Good to know.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this answer so you can mark this question answered.

As @calebboyd pointed out, this was raised as [an issue in GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3589) and closed when a note about the breaking change was added to the release notes of "[1.2.0rc1 spooky-giraffe (2013-08-13)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/9d6d3969f17f0c21f43e24d12dc8aa85a53cc9da/CHANGELOG.md#120rc1-spooky-giraffe-2013-08-13)". It's the last point under $compile in [Breaking Changes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/9d6d3969f17f0c21f43e24d12dc8aa85a53cc9da/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1):

> - due to [e46100f7](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e46100f7097d9a8f174bdb9e15d4c6098395c3f2), existing directives with name ending with "-start" or "-end" will stop working.
>
> This change was necessary to enable multi-element directives. The best fix is to rename existing directives, so that they don't end with these suffixes.